# What does this part of the Redux document mean?

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-testing-library, testing-library

I'm using the Redux-tool kit to set it up. We are now using @testing-library/react to set up testing-related settings.
I got a question while looking at the [official document](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components).

```js
// test-utils.js
import React from 'react'
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
// Import your own reducer
import reducer from '../reducer'

function render(
  ui,
  {
    initialState,
    store = createStore(reducer, initialState),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
  }
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions })
}

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react'
// override render method
export { render }
```

What function does this part have in the code part above?

```js
// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react'
// override render method
export { render }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this library, but `export * from '@testing-library/react'` just means that anything you can `import` from `@testing-library/react`, you can now import directly from this file, `test-utils.js`.

I guess that they found it convenient to have a way to access just the `react` testing modules in one place, with the `render` method overwritten with their own custom version defined above.

Answer (score 0):

They are basically creating their own aliased copy of the React Testing Library package where everything is the same except for the `render` function.  This setup is explained in more detail in the testing library docs section [Setup: Custom Render](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/#custom-render).

The custom `render` function [takes the same arguments](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#render) as the original `render` function from `@testing-library/react` so that they can be used interchangeably (though it adds support for extra properties `initialState` and `store` in the `options` object). Internally, the custom render function calls on the library's render function, which they import with an aliased name `rtlRender`, but it sets a default property for the [`wrapper` option](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#wrapper) so that components will be rendered inside of a redux `Provider` component.

Now to the confusing exports.  `export * from '@testing-library/react'` takes all of the exports from the testing library and re-exports them. `export { render }` overrides the previously exported render function with the custom one, so it needs to come after the `export *`.

As for why they would create the function in one place and then `export` it later rather than just doing `export function`, I think that's just a matter of code style preference.  This seems to work fine, as far as I can tell:

```
import { render as rtlRender } from "@testing-library/react";

// re-export everything
export * from "@testing-library/react";
// override render method
export function render(somethingCustom, ui, { ...renderOptions } = {}) {
  return rtlRender(ui, { ...renderOptions });
}
```